# Cannot find an exact (case-sensitive) match for 'lteRMCDL

Tags: matlab, case-sensitive, toolbox, lte

I tried to use the function lteRMCDL.m, but then it returns this:

```
x=lteRMCDL('R.5')
Cannot find an exact (case-sensitive) match for 'lteRMCDL'

The closest match is: LteRMCDL in
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/toolbox/lte/lteobsolete/LteRMCDL.m
```

Then, I tried LteRMCDL.m. Unfortunetely it returns:

```
x=LteRMCDL('R.5')
Cannot find an exact (case-sensitive) match for 'lteRMCDL'

The closest match is: LteRMCDL in
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/toolbox/lte/lteobsolete/LteRMCDL.m


Error in obsoleteLTEFunction (line 8)
[varargout{1:nargout}]= newfunction(args{:});

Error in LteRMCDL (line 12)
[varargout{1:nargout}] = obsoleteLTEFunction(mfilename,'lteRMCDL',varargin);
```

Has anyone already solve this kind of problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your MATLAB version? What does "which -all lteRMCDL" show?

Comment: My matlab's version is 2014a (8.3.0.534). 'which -all lteRMCDL/LteRMCDL' return: <br/> >> which -all lteRMCDL<br/>
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/toolbox/lte/lte/lteRMCDL.m  % Has no license available<br/>
>> which -all LteRMCDL<br/>
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/toolbox/lte/lteobsolete/LteRMCDL.m

Comment: Sorry about the bad formatting

Comment: It looks like you do not have license for lte toolbox. LteRMCDL is obsolete and just calls lteRMCDL.